# LaTeX news issue 24: who to contact

Tags: latex-project

The February issue of LaTeX news is out, but is not linked to from https://latex-project.org/ltnews/.  What to do?

Comment: See [here](https://latex-project.org/ltnews/ltnews24.pdf).

Comment: I know.  I said it wasn't linked to from the page, not that it hasn't been uploaded :)

Comment: Presumably the webmaster (https://latex-project.org/contact.html), though I'm sure there are people around who knows for sure.

Comment: I must say that I was browsing the site for around 5 minutes, and I missed the Impressum link. I think the website is poorly designed. This should be in the footer, or in some other prominent place, like in the bottom center right next to the acknowledgment regarding the lion image.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report on the LaTeX project website.

Comment: Please do not take it as that it's wrong to report a bug in LP website, but as such, it is not on-topic.

Comment: yo: I know it's not wrong to report a bug: my point is I know not how or where or to whom!

Comment: @Mark the contact page on the old site has contact details but see the test version of a new site (which will appear at the existing project url shortly) http://latex3.github.io/latex-project.org/

Comment: @Mark Good point. `:-)`